# How to Checked a checkbox when there is a certain value in the text field

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textfield which contains certain value:

```
 <input class="form-control" name="user_id" id="studID" type="text" maxlength="255" value="61,62,63,64"/>
```

this is the input checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox"   name="user_id[] value="61" />
<input type="checkbox"   name="user_id[] value="62" />
<input type="checkbox"   name="user_id[] value="63" />
```

*note i run this checkbox in php thats why it contains the [] for array.

I want the checkbox to checked if there is a value of 61 inside the textfield. I want it to be dynamic because it is from database, because value can be change and it is not fixed. How do i do this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```js
 let ids = $('#studID').val().split(',');
    ids.forEach(function(id) {
       $('input[type="checkbox"][value="'+id+'"]').prop('checked',true);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" name="user_id" id="studID" type="text" maxlength="255" value="61,62,63,64"/>

<input type="checkbox"   name="user_id[]" value="61" />
<input type="checkbox"   name="user_id[]" value="62" />
<input type="checkbox"   name="user_id[]" value="63" />
<input type="checkbox"   name="user_id[]" value="66" />
<input type="checkbox"   name="user_id[]" value="67" />
<input type="checkbox"   name="user_id[]" value="68" />
```

```js
 let ids = $('#studID').val().split(',');
    ids.forEach(function(id) {
       $('input[type="checkbox"][value="'+id+'"]').prop('checked',true);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" name="user_id" id="studID" type="text" maxlength="255" value="61,62,63,64"/>

<input type="checkbox"   name="user_id[]" value="61" />
<input type="checkbox"   name="user_id[]" value="62" />
<input type="checkbox"   name="user_id[]" value="63" />
<input type="checkbox"   name="user_id[]" value="66" />
<input type="checkbox"   name="user_id[]" value="67" />
<input type="checkbox"   name="user_id[]" value="68" />
```

plain javascript

```js
let ids = document.querySelector("#studID").value.split(',');
    ids.forEach(function(id) {
      var checkbox = document.querySelector("input[name='user_id[]'][value='"+id+"']");
      if(checkbox) {
         checkbox.checked = true;
      }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" name="user_id" id="studID" type="text" maxlength="255" value="61,62,63,64"/>

<input type="checkbox"   name="user_id[]" value="61" />
<input type="checkbox"   name="user_id[]" value="62" />
<input type="checkbox"   name="user_id[]" value="63" />
<input type="checkbox"   name="user_id[]" value="66" />
<input type="checkbox"   name="user_id[]" value="67" />
<input type="checkbox"   name="user_id[]" value="68" />
```

Comment: OP did not ask for a jQuery solution neither there is a tag for it in the post.

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate over the inputs and then check the condition:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(function(i) {
  if (i.value.indexOf("61") > -1) {
    i.checked = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="user_id[]" value=" 61 " />
<input type="checkbox" name="user_id[]" value="62" />
<input type="checkbox" name="user_id[]" value=" 63" />
```

Comment: Where is the text box that contains the dynamic value he wants to search for in the checkboxes?

Comment: @Barmar OP didn't mention that. He needed a way to check the input based on a  certain value. He mentioned 61 for example and that has been used in the answer as well. He can use this as a starting point

Comment: @KK He wrote: **I want it to be dynamic because it is from database, because value can be change and it is not fixed**

Answer (score 1):

Add a `change` listener to the text field. It should loop through the checkboxes, either checking or unchecking them depending on whether their values match the input.

```js
document.querySelector("#studID").addEventListener("change", function() {
  var values = this.value.split(",");
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(`input[name='user_id[]']`);
  checkboxes.forEach(cb => cb.checked = values.includes(cb.value));
});
```

```html
<input class="form-control" name="user_id" id="studID" type="text" maxlength="255" value="61,62,63,64" />
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="user_id[]" value="61" />
<input type="checkbox" name="user_id[]" value="62" />
<input type="checkbox" name="user_id[]" value="63" />
```

Comment: hello i tried this does not checked the checkbox though :0

Comment: You have to edit the input field and then press Return for the `change` event to be triggered.

Comment: So if you change it to `61,63` it will check those boxes.